# adding promises to an array of promises in a for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

let's assume the following example:

```
var bb = require('bluebird');

var promiseStack = [];
var deferred = bb.defer();

promiseStack.push(deferred.promise);

bb.delay(2500).then(function() {
    deferred.resolve();
});

bb.all(promiseStack).then(function() {
    console.log('done');
});
```

Why isn't it possible to do the following:

```
var bb = require('bluebird');

var promiseStack = [];


for(var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    var deferred = bb.defer();
    promiseStack.push(deferred.promise);

    bb.delay(2500).then(function() {
        deferred.resolve();
    });
}

bb.all(promiseStack).then(function() {
    console.log('done');
});
```

It takes aprox. 2500ms but `console.log('done')` isn't called.
What's the problem with, am I doing wrong?

The best,
redshark1802

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What's the problem with, am I doing wrong?

Your `deferred` variable is not local to the loop body, but on a global scope. You're overwriting it each time with a new Deferred, and resolving only the last of them (but multiple times).

To fix it, you could try a [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example), but you [shouldn't use `Deferred` anyway](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#wiki-the-deferred-anti-pattern). Just use the promise you already have!

```
var bb = require('bluebird');

var promiseStack = [];

for(var i = 1; i < 10; i++) // 1 to 9 ???
    promiseStack.push( bb.delay(2500) );

bb.all(promiseStack).then(function() {
    console.log('done');
});
```